# Where is the as3 json lib on adobe site?

Tags: flash, json

it is said
http://www.darronschall.com/weblog/2006/02/actionscript-3-json-library-now-available.cfm

You can download the JSON library as part of the core ActionScript 3 library.

but when clicking on the link it doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The as3corelib, including com.adobe.serialization with the JSON stuff, is now on github:

https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib